# how post json object when my object containing other object?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have two simple class.

```
public class account_ {
        public String account_id;
        public String fname ;
        public String lname ;

        public loging_REQUIREMENT login_R;
}
public class loging_REQUIREMENT{
    public String login_id;
    public String login_key;
    .
    .
}
```

I use Volley for post/put data to the server.

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url + "profile", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            volleyCallback.onSuccess(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            volleyCallback.onError(error+"");
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("account_id",account_.account_id);
            params.put("fname",account_.fname);
            params.put("lname",account_.lname);

            params.put("login_R", ********* my problem*******   );
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

in this case, i try to put "login_R" manually but it doesn't work because automatically put some Quotation before and after that and give me JSON syntax error, and now I can't put "log_R" in "params". how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an instance of your `loging_REQUIREMENT` Object into a function that expects a `String` Object. That's not allowed. You can only pass:

`login_R.login_id` or `login_R.login_key`

as those are `String`s as well. If you need to pass entire object as a JSON string, you have to convert it into a JSON representation. [Here](https://github.com/google/gson) is the most widely used library for that.

PS. It helps everyone dealing with your code when [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) are followed. Makes code easier to read. Most relevant one is

> class name should start with uppercase letter and be a noun e.g. String, Color, Button, System, Thread etc.